# PouchDb - remove object inside document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, pouchdb

I'm an Italian PouchDb and AngularJS Developer. 
My json document is:

```
{
   "_id": "6",
   "_rev": "3-f7283d7683cd6fb15753f494aad1d49f",
   "name": "Ivrea",
   "owners": [
       {
           "owner_id": 1,
           "name": "asdas",
           "address": "asdas",
           "gender": "Uomo",
           "type": "Assente",
           "notes": [
           ]
       },
       {
           "owner_id": 2,
           "name": "balbaba",
           "address": "blabla",
           "gender": "Uomo",
           "type": "Assente",
           "notes": [
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

and after an `ng-click` action, I will delete `owner_id: 2` object inside `_id: 6` document. In API reference I found only document delete action, but not how to delete object inside document.

Thanks for your reply!!

Alessandro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `put()` the main document back in the database after you remove an object from it.  :)

```
db.get('foo').then(function (doc) {
  delete doc.whatever;
  return db.put(doc);
}).catch(function (err) { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: Using delete keyword I do `delete result.rows[0].doc.VerificationToken;` and then `db.saveDoc(result.rows[0].doc)` but when I see the db, `VerificationToken` is still there. Not sure why, when I debug, `delete` keyword actually deletes the key and the doc that's being saved is without `VerificationToken`